Should I commit supabase/.branch/ and supabase/.temp/ files?
When working with Supabase, it created the following files locally:
/supabase
  .branches/
    _current_branch
  .temp/
    cli-latest
    gotrue-version
    pooler-url
    postgres-version
    rest-version
    storage-version

The content of files are for example:

cli-latest: v2.1.1
gotrue-version: v2.167.0

Should I track these files with git or should I add them to my .gitignore?

It comes down to what the content of the generated files is. Are they ephemeral files that are only relevant to your current environment? If someone else on another machine pulls your repo, would they need the generated files to execute the code? Can the same generated files be recreated easily by executing a script or re running the application?
Version control is for tracking the history of changes in your source code. In general generated files should not be checked into VCS because there is no benefit to doing so and they can easily be regenerated.
